# calculate the difference between two dates (a user input date and today's date)

Tags: date

```
from datetime import date

Initial_date = input ("what is the date: ")
```

**user input date in yy:mm:dd format**

```
today = date.today()

d1 = date.strftime(initial_date)
```

**conversion of date from string to date format**

```
d2 = (today)

delta = (d2 - d1)

print (delta)
```

I am trying to find out the difference in two dates; user input date (e.g 2023-08-31) and Today's date. It should give me the # of days left.
I am getting following error "TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already close with your solution, but you have to make a few small adjustments

1. When getting user input, make sure to parse it into a **date** object using the appropriate format
2. Extract the number of days from the timedelta object using the **.days** attribute

Here is the final code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

initial_date_str = input("what is the date (yyyy-mm-dd): ")
initial_date = datetime.strptime(initial_date_str, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

today = date.today()

delta = (initial_date - today).days

print("Number of days left:", delta)
```